# How to keep HTML entities while parsing HTML with lxml?

Tags: python, html, lxml, html-entities

Is there a way to configure lxml to not strip HTML entities? i.e.

```
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True, remove_blank_text=True, remove_comments=True)

html = '<html><body><p>&agrave;</body><p></html>'
parsed_tree = etree.XML(html, parser))
etree.tostring(parsed_tree) # returns '<html><body><p/><p/></body></html>'
```

I would like to keep the `&agrave;` in the HTML and not get it stripped out.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it switching `etree.XMLParser` to `etree.HTMLParser` and `etree.XML` to `etree.HTML`.